# Method inside another function doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, methods

I've created a function(new Soldier) in a .js that creates an object with Class="unit" that when clicked, it will provide some information. When I put the function outside of all other functions(but still inside `$(document).ready(function() {})`, it works perfectly. But when I put it inside another function(that contains an if statement), it creates the object(or at least the image), but the object doesn't do anything when clicked.

The one that works is simply:

```
Unit[selectedindex] = new Soldier(selectedindex);
```

But when set like this:

```
$('#startingSoldier').click(function() {
    Unit[selectedindex] = new Soldier(selectedindex);
}
});
```

The object it creates doesn't work when clicked.  I have a `$('.unit').click(function(){}`.

Let me know if you need additional information on the  click function or the Soldier method. Thank you for your help.

Comment: It sounds like you aren't properly binding the click event. Try putting a `console.log` in your click event and make sure it's firing.

Comment: dont you have a extra } at the end of the code ? `$('#startingSoldier').click(function(){
    Unit[selectedindex] = new Soldier(selectedindex);
**}** 
});`

Comment: Do you get any error message in the error console? As the code that you use is the same, it has to be the meaning of the variables that you uses that differs, so it would help if you show a little more code.

Comment: Just to make sure that it's not something easy, you do have an extra `}` in your code block and are missing the ending `);` in your last function that you included inline in the second-to-last paragraph.  Just wanting to make sure it's not a simple syntax error.   :)

Comment: There's not an error that I can see. Please ignore the extra }, I copied the parts I thought were relevant, and deleted some others, and missed some things. The click event is definitely firing, It does the other things inside it, and creates the .unit object. It's just that afterwards, it does not allow me to do the .unit click event.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I guess I figured it out. The .unitclick event had to also be inside the startingsoldier click event. I don't understand why, but it works now.